# array index and undefined help needed in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array that I populate from a JSON-field from my SQL database.
It is a quite complicated structure, like this.

> id1:
>         0:
>           id2:
>              30:
>                0:
>                  0: val1
>                  1: val2
>                1:
>                  0: val1
>                  1: val2
>              34:
>                0:
>                  0: val1
>                  1: val2
>                1:
>                  0: val1
>                  1: val2
>                2:
>                  0: val1
>                  1: val2
>                3:
>                  0: val1
>                  1: val2
>        2:
>          ...

My problem as I define this is that I first get undefined and also I can not seem to access the first column.
The array I generate from this is without the texts (or at least this is my intention).

The code is like this:

```
ar = [];
```

... long hierarchy where I break down the json-input
... and comes in the end up with:

```
// Create object
if(typeof ar[id1] == 'undefined'){ //id1 is the first identitier
    ar[id1] = [];
}
if(typeof ar[id1][id2] == 'undefined'){
    ar[id1][id2] = [];
}
ar[id1][id2].push([val1, val2]);
```

When I print this out I get:
    (3) [Array(46), undefined × 1, Array(49)]
    0: Array(46)
      30: Array(10)
        0: Array(2)
           0: "val1"
           1: "val2"
        1: Array(2)
           0: "val1"
           1: "val2"
      34: Array(22)
        0: Array(2)
        1: Array(2)
        2: Array(2)
        3: Array(2)
    2: Array(49) ...

The length is incorrect and it will be undefined.
Besides I can't access the id1-value from my array.
Where do I go wrong?

My code:

```
for (index in ar) {
    console.log("Id1wwe: ", ar[index]);
    console.log("Id1www: ", ar[index].length);
    console.log("Id1wwa: ", ar[0].length);
    console.log("Id1wwb: ", ar.length);
}

console.log("Length: ", ar.length);
for(let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
    let tmpId1 = ar[i];
    console.log("Id1: ", ar[i]);
}
```

It will not work.
Any hints?

/Fredrik.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? The JSON fields that you have is confusing.

Comment: I am trying to use the array that I fill to update another array for filling an option value on my screen with only valid entries depending on entered id1 and id2 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using for your data wrong structure: think about `{}` instead of `[]` for your `ar` variable, then you will be able to

- Have access to your nested arrays by index
- Have correct length of structure with `Object.keys(ar).length`

Comment: So I am creating the object first and then array structure?

Comment: @Popeye right, for object you can use any index as a key. Array is an object btw :D

Comment: @Popeye if you post input and output data examples, we could help to achieve what you would like to get

Comment: I tried with object and now it works.
I have to go through object.key, which creates an array of the id:s and then collect it individually, so it seems.
Thank you for all help :)

Comment: @Popeye I'm glad I could help